# Getting a random value from an array to edit .css with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, arrays

I'm trying to get the border-color to change on every button click to a random color from the array but it only picks a random color from the array once for the border-color and does not change to a random color on each button click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var nextBtnClicks = 0,
        previousBtnClicks = 0,
        colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'],
        random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    $('#NxtBtn').click(function () {
        if (nextBtnClicks < 8) {
            $('#image').animate({left: '-=640px'}, 500, function () {
                $('#pic_box').css('border-color', random_color);
            });
            nextBtnClicks += 1;
        } else {
            $('#image').animate({left: '0px'}, 500);
            nextBtnClicks = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the random_color variable outside of the click function so it just sets and stays there.  Move the line to inside the .click function.